"Object.groupBy does not exist" error when running Jest tests on Node 20
I have some code using the Object.groupBy method. This is in codebase using TypeScript 5.5 and everything is working well.
Lately I've tried to add some tests and I get the error Property 'groupBy' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.
Jest is set up to use ts-jest to transform the TypeScript code:
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(ts|tsx|js)$": [
        "ts-jest",
        {
          "tsconfig": "<rootDir>/tsconfig.json",
          "isolatedModules": true
        }
      ]
    }

and the tsconfig.json is:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2018",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "strict": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noImplicitOverride": true,
        "lib": [
            "ESNext",
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src"
    ]
}

As as far as I understand my test code should be transpiled using this config into code valid for ES2018 which should be fully supported by Node 20.
What generates a failure and how can I fix it?

You said you're using Node 20 and wanted ES2018, but then claim "lib": ["ESNext"]. That's not consistent. Try using e.g. @tsconfig/node20 as a base, which sets the appropriate configuration. TypeScript does not polyfill, so you need to tell it what's actually going to be available (and not) at runtime for it to help you.

According to MDN, Object.groupBy was only introduced in Node.js 21.0.0.
This is also referenced in the Node.js 21 release notes (see "Array Grouping" in the "Notable Changes" section).
To make a long story short - you need Node.js 21 to use Object.groupBy, not Node.js 20.

I'm aware of that. but since the target of the tsconfig.js file is ES2018 isn't the code transpiled to be compatible with older versions of node too?

It's a JavaScript feature, it shouldn't be transpiled. If you're using an older Node.js version, you can use a polyfil.

"It's a JavaScript feature, it shouldn't be transpiled."  But it is when using ts-node or tsc. Why not when using ts-jest? Is this behavior documented anywhere?

I had to add "ESNext" to compilerOptions.lib in tsconfig:
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["DOM", "ESNext"],

